# Difference between using a relation and returning a relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a newbie Rails question about the difference between using a relation and returning a relation:

So I have a `Folder` class that `has_many :files`. Originally, I defined the following in the ActiveRecord file for `Folder`:

```
def visible_files
   files.where(:hidden => false, :online => true)  # This returns a relation, right?
end
```

Now, let's say I'm switching that to an explicit relation:

```
has_many :visible_files
         :class_name => 'File',
         :conditions => 'hidden is false and online is true'
```

What are the differences between these two approaches? I suspect the latter is preferred, but I'd like to know why. Are there any performance reasons for preferring one over the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both do the same thing, just in different ways: they provide a way to get all the visible and online files.

What the `has_many` version does differently is that it provides extra association stuff, [as documented in the "Associations Guide"](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-many-association-reference). Some of these features will exist on the relation returned by the method (such as `create`), but others such as `build` won't.